# Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\Python\PLAY.PY", line 29, in <module>

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Need Help in this code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\PLAY.PY", line 29, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\Python\chromedriver.exe', desired_capabilities=capa, options=options)  # Arguments
  File "C:\Users\Virus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Virus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Virus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Virus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Virus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.
```

Comment: Why are you using `desired_capabilities` ?

Comment: Can you run `D:\Python\chromedriver.exe` from a command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You NEED to get in the habit of escaping backslashes. Use one of these options:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\Python\\chromedriver.exe',desired_capabilities=capa, options=options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'D:\Python\chromedriver.exe',desired_capabilities=capa, options=options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/Python/chromedriver.exe',desired_capabilities=capa, options=options)
```

Comment: Neither `'\P'` nor `'\c'` is a special character. So, no, it was not the problem.